# Gossip Girl Locations in NYC

Tags: usa, sightseeing, new-york-city

I am hoping to go to NYC soon and want to know the top places to visit while I'm there. I am obsessed with Gossip Girl and want to go to those locations in the TV series.

Comment: Obessions are dangerous...

Comment: It's mostly around Manhattan, if I had to take a guess. Upper East Side a lot.

Answer (score 8):

There are tours for the locations in New York City more specifically:

- [OnLocation Tours](http://onlocationtours.com/tour/gossip-girl/)
- [Gray Line](http://www.newyorksightseeing.com/tourpage.php?item=GGT)
- [City Sites](http://www.citysightsny.com/tourpage.php?item=GGT)

So pick your poison but this list is likely incomplete.

Answer (score 8):

Someone's also put together a definitive list of all the locations they could find in the series, [together on one map](http://www.vulture.com/2010/09/the_definitive_gossip_girl_loc.html).  It's amazingly detailed, and so anywhere on Manhattan that you happen to be, you're probably near a location.

Another [larger map is available as well, with captions](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=106524979103268226087.00046b7640e9309aefa26&dg=feature).

However rather than wander aimlessly trying to see each one, your best bet is to take one of the several tours available specifically for this, from the companies mentioned in @Karlson's answer.